# the google play services resources were not found . admob program crashed

Tags: android, eclipse, admob, google-play-services

I was trying add admob banner in a application. I downloaded all updates for Eclipse and SDK.

Also in the manifest I

1)Add a meta-data tag;

2)Declare com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity;

3)Set up network permissions.

Add the Google Play services library project I also didnt forgot

This is xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000" >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-98743015.........." />
```

I think the problem is in xml because there is a **The following classes could not be instantiated:**  but despite the problems the application works

This is code in activity

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

and in onCreate:

```
AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and finally we got to logcat **The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure to the resources are included.** This problems appears three times in a row.

If the program is long used they are crashed and in logcat

```
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:                           Unable to find explicit activity class {com.svyART.idd/com.svyART.idd.Nakleyki}; have you          declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at     android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1756)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1555)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at   android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3431)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at     android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3392)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at com.svyART.idd.Idn$1.onItemClick(Idn.java:458)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1223)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:4506)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2967)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3653)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225):    at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I would be very grateful for your help

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the `google-play-services-lib` as a library-project. Open the SDK Manager and check it on the list to be downloaded. Then you'll find it into `android-sdk-x/extras/google_play_services/libproject`

Then from Eclipse, **right-click** your project, go to **Properties** and add the .jar.

Comment: I add google-play-services-lib this way **right-click** , **Properties** , **Android** then I add a library. Also I was try add a google-play-services.jar in **right-click** , **Properties** ,**Java Build Path** , **Add External JARs..** but this didnt help me.

Comment: And yes, I copy google-play-services-lib in my project

Answer (score 1):

Your stackltrace is very clear about why it is failing.

```
07-22 16:20:57.507: E/AndroidRuntime(26225): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:                           Unable to find explicit activity class {com.svyART.idd/com.svyART.idd.Nakleyki}; have you          declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

It is trying to start an Activity called `com.svyART.idd.Nakleyki` when a ListView item is clicked, but the Activity is not declared in your AndroidManifest. Add it to AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

> The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project
>   configuration to ensure that the resources are included.

can be safely ignored as stated in the [Google Mobile Ads SDK FAQ](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/kb/#resourcesnotfound).

Don't ask me why Google Play Services write some much confusing stuff to the log and why Google is unable to fix it. The problem isn't exactly new.

Comment: Unfortunately my program crashes. 
maybe the problem not in is?

Comment: Now that's an interesting information you forgot to mention. You even wrote: *"but despite the problems the application works"*. I propose you add the stacktrace of the crash to your question.

Comment: it was a rhetorical question )

Comment: I try find why my program crashes and then I ask you how I must resolve my issue. Thanks!

Comment: When I remove all the codes associated with the admob program is working fine!

Comment: I find a many mistakes in my project so I change my code and then if issue not resolved I made a new questions or remake this.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Lack of experience in programming led me the wrong way.Indeed you can be **safely ignored** as stated in the Google Mobile Ads SDK FAQ.